# How to prevent Traefik from serving default self-signed certificat

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nexus, traefik-ingress

i am trying to setup nexus 3 docker registry behind traefik v2.3.1, the problem is when i want to do

```
docker login <docker_url> -u <user> -p <password>
```

i receive this error

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker_url/v1/users/: x509: certificate is valid for 6ddc59ad70b84f1659f8ffb82376935b.6f07c26f5a92b019cea10818bc6b7b7e.traefik.default, not docker_url
```

Treafik parameters

```
          - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80/tcp"
          - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443/tcp"
          - "--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp"
          - "--api.dashboard=true"
          - "--api.insecure"
          - "--ping=true"
          - "--providers.kubernetescrd"
          - "--providers.kubernetesingress"
          - "--log.level=DEBUG"
          - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
```

IngressRouteTCP

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nexus
spec:
  routes:
    - match: Host(`docker_url`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: nexus-svc
          port: 5000
```

in nexus 3 i configured a docker registry to listen on port 5000 using http

so my question is it realy i need only treafik to stop serving default self-singed cert or there is another problem that i don't see

thanks for the help in advance